# Router common vulnerabilities

Tags: router

Do you know any list (like OWASP top 10 of web vulnerabilities) for router vulnerabilities?

If not what are the top 10 vulnerabilities that you can find in routers regardless of version/brand?

Comment: Are you asking about home routers, or the kind of stuff that runs the internet? I'm not sure about an OWASP type list, but I'd imagine that default creds comes somewhere near the top of a list for routers. If you're asking about home routers, the web interface could fall under OWASP

Comment: I am not referring to default creds I am referring to a list like: 1) XSS 2) Remote code execution ... but only for routers :)  regardless of home or enterprise (..if possible)

Comment: Home routers (NAT devices) are except for the name fundamentally different from routers that run the internet. This might be too broad.

Comment: CSRF , Basic Authentication in plain text/base64,LFI are the ones i came across mostly with common(home) routers

Comment: @Sravan  can you put in answer?

Comment: @dvvcnxc I cant find a some kind of research proof that can say CSRF,LFI,Basic Auth are the most prevalent in routers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OWASP Top 10 exists because OWASP surveys web applications and ranks the most common problems found.

There is no such project for routers, and firmware updates, model changes, and new products (and product approaches) would make that list difficult to maintain.

Because routers use web pages, and routers are written in software, it is reasonable to extrapolate that the OWASP Top 10 and the SANS Top 20 will also affect routers, but there is no router-specific list.